# Need to remove every third element in a list of 10 elements - getting index error

Tags: python, list

I keep getting IndexError: list assignment index out of range. My logic is as follows: The print(x) shows that 6 is printed out before getting the error. Working through the code logically, 6 % 4 == 0 is true, so the code should delete numbers[6 - 1] which is numbers[5]. After that, x is incremented to 7, and the loop will not iterate again.

Can someone please point out where I am incorrect? TIA.

```
# create list from user specifications
numbers = []
size = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))

for i in range(0, size):
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter an element: ")))

# Iterate through each element. If an elements index is a multiple of 3,
# delete it.
x = 1
while x <= size:
    print(x)
    if ((x) % 3) == 0:
        del(numbers[x - 1])
    x = x + 1

print("The list is: ")
print(numbers)
```

Comment: When posting a question, avoid user input in scripts when possible. In your case, `numbers` and `size` could be hard coded. This makes it easier for us to run the example.

Comment: Try adding a `print(numbers)` after `print(x)`. You are modifying the list as you loop making it shorter. Eventually it becomes shorter than your index, which leads to an error.

Comment: Do you need to change the current list or would it be okay to create a new list, discarding values as we go?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the array changes size during the loop. When the index is indeed a multiple of three, the `del` operation removes the element from the array, thus `numbers` no longer have a size of `size`, but your index variable `x` will still go up to the value of `size-1` which is above the last index of your modified array.

An easy way is to build a copy of the list instead of removing elements from it, and ignoring all elements with index multiple of 3.

```py
# create list from user specifications
numbers = []
size = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))

for i in range(0, size):
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter an element: ")))

# Iterate through each element. If an elements index is a multiple of 3,
# delete it.
x = 1
filtered = []
while x <= size:
    print(x)
    if not ((x % 3) == 0):
        filtered.append(numbers[x-1])
    x = x + 1

numbers = filtered 

print("The list is: ")
print(numbers)
```

Comment: I now understand why I was incorrect. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an item in a list, the remaining items shift left, changing their index. After the first delete, you either have to change your index value or use a different technique completely. Python is well suited for filtering lists with "comprehensions". Use that, and the `enumerate` function that will emit the values plus their index, and you can simplify this greatly.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
numbers = [value for index, value in enumerate(numbers, 1) if index % 3]
print(numbers)
```